# XML Schema restriction

Tags: xsd

```
<xs:complexType name="GeographySegment_Type">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Directionality" type="Directionality_Type"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="ExcludeInclude" type="ExcludeInclude_Type" use="required" default="E"/>
    </xs:complexType>
<xs:simpleType name="ExcludeInclude_Type">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="E"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="I"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
```

I want to specify a default value for attribute EXcludeInclude as well as make it mandatory by use="required" but i am getting an error-In attribute declaration excluseInclude use must have the value optional because the attribute default is present.
What is the workaround?

Answer (score 0):

What is your purpose for supplying a default value? Normally the default value is the value assumed when there is the attribute is absent, so a default value has no purpose when the attribute is required to be present.